# Guacamole VNC File Transfer

Tags: javascript, java, servlets, vnc, guacamole

I am using Guacamole HTML5 clientless VNC viewer. I am trying to upload a file via Guacamole over VNC. Is this possible?

I looked at the application's homepage and this function seems possible. There is an event called `onfile` in `guacamole.all.js`, but there isn't a code sample to replicate this functionality.

How do I upload a file via Guacamole over VNC?

Comment: can you explain what research you have done yourself to try and find a solution to this?

Comment: I just read in guacamole website , it seems possible.Then , There is event 'onfile'  in guacamole.all.js.  There is no code example.

Answer (score 1):

Guacamole uses SFTP to transfer files back and forward to the computer, so it doesn't transfer files over the VNC connection like TightVNC can. This means that you will have to setup an SFTP server on the computer running the VNC-server to be able to transfer files to the computer. If you have done that, you will have to provide the SFTP server details in your connection details page.

Once everything is setup properly you can start uploading and downloading files. For uploading you need to set a "standard uploading directory" in your connection properties. To upload something to that directory simply drag a file and drop it in the view screen in your browser. A little dialog with the upload process will appear and the file will be transferred to the remote computer!

For downloading open the guacamole menu while viewing your remote computer by pressing ctrl+alt+shift. If everything is setup properly you will see a device which you can browse and select the files you want to download. Good luck with this.

P.S. If the VNC-server is running on a windows machine, look at freeFTPd. It's a free lightweight program that can be setup to start at windows startup. Perfect solution for using with guacamole. If you are running linux it shouldn't be too hard to find an sftp server.